# How to query all sessions that are using a VIEW?

Tags: sql, oracle, repository, informatica

I'm looking for a way to query the repository tables of informatica and get back all the sessions that are using a view.

These are the tables I searched in :

```
      OPB_SESS_FILE_VALS
      OPB_SESSION
      OPB_MAPPING
      OPB_SUBJECT
      OPB_TASK
      REP_SESSION_INSTANCES
      OPB_TASK_INST
```

I tried to search online, go through almost all the tables but didn't find a way to know if a task is a view or not . 
I can use `TASK_NAME LIKE 'V_%'` but it won't be 100% correct as not all our views are named standard .

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by View? Can you explain clearly

Comment: A `source` / `lookup` can be a table \ a flat file\csv and a VIEW . If they are views, I want them . @JimMacaulay

Comment: Informatica takes the data as a source from the database , it will not identify whether it is a view or a table. Its just a source from the database.

Comment: You have one solution for this, if you know all the view names you required - you can have them in the query and get your details

Comment: I don't that's the whole point. I just want an indication on each session if they are using a VIEW or not. I'm sure at least one of the repository tables contain this information (After all , when you import a table to informatica, Tables and Views are placed in different schemas) . @JimMacaulay

Comment: Informatica is not aware of the DB object nature. All it knows is the name of it so it can be quieried - regardless of whether it's a view or a table. And if it's a source, it's created in a folder named after ODBC used to create it. If you create a target, all lands in the same node.